# schedulig a batch file to run in every 2 mins in java

Tags: java

I have created a batch file named abc.bat which perform some task for me but rite now I have to execute it manually after every 10 minutes , please advise how can I schedule it so that it can run as service in windows I was looking for any java program or quartz implementation that will run after every five minutes and will execute that batch file abc.bat, Please advise how can I schedule to execute the batch file in java.

Comment: Why do you need Java for this?  Doesn't Windows have a task scheduler?

Comment: @Davide I want to execute this batch after every 2 mins, I have some requirement to go for java program,specially on windows

Comment: Windows has a scheduler. You don't need a Java program to do that. http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/schedule-a-task

Comment: @user2035385: `"I have some requirement to go for java program,specially on windows"` - That's a pretty arbitrary requirement.  I suppose you could write a one-line Java program that just opens the Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: @David i doubt that it is easier to start the windows task scheduler from a one line java program. (do one need administrator rigths for that?)

Answer (score 1):

I Java there is the class `TimerTask` to execute something on regular interval.
Then in that timer run the bat with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start myjob.bat");
```