# execute batch through timer class

Tags: java

I have a batch file in my C: drive named abc.bat which I want to execute every two minutes. I have to do this with Java. I need to use the `TimerTask` class. Below is my current code:

```
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;


// Create a class extends with TimerTask
public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {

    // Add your task here
    public void run() {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start abc.bat");
    }
}

//Main class
public class SchedulerMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        Timer time = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object
        ScheduledTask st = new ScheduledTask(); // Instantiate SheduledTask class
        time.schedule(task, now ,TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));

    }
}
```

Comment: There was good advise given in the comments in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662928/schedulig-a-batch-file-to-run-in-every-2-mins-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `abc.bat` file is located in `c:\` then use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start c:\\abc.bat");
```

Also you need to create

```
java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
```

if you want to use it in `time.schedule(task, now ,TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));` 

or just use `time.schedule(task, new java.util.Date() ,TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));`

Comment: Thanks a lot, also please advise if I make the executable jar of the program and execute it then it would also continue to run.